# CocoaPods pod install is removing some build phases

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have inherited a project which uses CocoaPods for its dependencies. This is the first time I have used CocoaPods.

Based on `Podfile.lock` it looks like the CocoaPods version used the last time the project was built was 1.8.4; I am using 1.9.3.

The Xcode project file has some build phases that were generated by CocoaPods, such as

```
[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock
[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks
[CP] Copy Pods Resources
```

After running `pod install`, the "Embed Pods" and "Copy Pods" phases get removed, which means that when I run the app, it can't find those frameworks.

Of course, I could just drag the missing frameworks into the Embedded Frameworks section, but this is tedious since there are 41 (!!) dependencies in the Podfile, so I'm wondering if there is something I am missing.